# Finding a minimum bounding sphere for a frustum

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, geometry, frustum

I have a frustum (truncated pyramid) and I need to compute a bounding sphere for this frustum that's as small as possible. I can choose the centre to be right in the centre of the frustum and the radius be the distance to one of the "far" corners, but that usually leaves quite a lot of slack around the narrow end of the frustum

This seems like simple geometry, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this is a question better suited for http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: What is this regarding? OpenGL?

Comment: Has nothing to do with OpenGL or anything specific like that. Just need a sphere that encloses a frustum.

Comment: @sklitzz:  Mathoverflow is for graduate-level mathematics, not this.

Comment: Bob: if you don't tell us how you need to use this in a program, etc., the math-challenged on this site will close your question as "Not Programming Related."  So tell us how its programming related.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but you could compute all the verts of the frustum and plug them into a general minimum bounding sphere algorithm, like [the miniball implementation](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html).

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Minimal_enclosing_sphere of course (via Google).

I'd think there are two possibilities. One (if the frustum is very flat) would be that the opposite points of the base become opposite points on the sphere. The other (if the frustum is very tall) would be that opposite points of the frustum would be on the sphere and you'd figure out the sphere from those four points (one point on the base, one opposite the first on the base, one opposite the first on the higher square, one adjacent the first on the higher square).

Figure out the first sphere. If the frustum fits in it, that's your answer. Otherwise, the second sphere would be your answer.

Comment: Good observation that there are 2 distinct solutions to consider. Sphere center is in the center of the base unless a frustum top vertex is farther away than a base vertex from that point.

Answer (score 4):

There are several algorithms and implementations out there for this problem (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395178/given-n-points-in-a-3d-space-how-to-find-the-smallest-sphere-that-contains-thes/14979145#14979145)).

- For 2D and 3D, [Gärtner's implementation](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html) is probably the fastest.
- For higher dimensions (up to 10,000, say), take a look at https://github.com/hbf/miniball, which is the implementation of an algorithm by Gärtner, Kutz, and Fischer (note: I am one of the co-authors).
- For very, very high dimensions, *core-set* (approximation) algorithms will be faster.

In your particular application, you may want to try either of the first two algorithms. Both run in `O(n)` with a very small constant and are numerically stable.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to find a sphere that fits 4 points on your frustum.   If this is a proper frustum (a truncated pyramid - my bad I was assuming a cylindrical fristum), then you get two points from opposite corners of the top quad, and the other two from the bottom quad, out of phase with the top two.  Then use [this](http://home.att.net/~srschmitt/zenosamples/zs_sphere4pts.html) to get your sphere.

Comment: Actually, the selection of points depends on the height of the frustum. If it is very short, all of the points may be from the same quad (and then you actually need only 3 points)

Comment: Link is dead (it is good practice to copy out the important parts from a linked answer I guess for this reason :)

Answer (score 2):

Well let's solve with math.

Using right hand Y up coordinate system (forward is –Z axis), for frustum with viewport width w, height h, near plane n, far plane f, X axis field of view angle fov, then the minimal bounding sphere is

```
k = sqrt(1+(h/w)^2) * tan⁡(fov/2)

if( k^2 >= (f-n)/(f+n) )
{
    C = (0, 0, -f)
    R = f*k
}
else
{
    C = (0, 0, -0.5 * (f+n) * (1+k^2))
    R = 0.5 * sqrt( (f-n)^2 + 2*(f^2+n^2)*k^2 + (f+n)^2*k^4 )
}
```

C is the center of the sphere, in view space, and R is radius.

I put details in my blog if you are interested:
https://lxjk.github.io/2017/04/15/Calculate-Minimal-Bounding-Sphere-of-Frustum.html

Answer (score 0):

Any set of four noncoplanar points defines a sphere.  Assuming you're using a four-sided pyramid for your frustum, there are 70 possible sets of four points.  Try all 70 spheres and see which is the smallest.

Given that your frustum probably has some symmetries, you can probably pick the four points on opposite corners and use plinth's solution.

Comment: Most sets of four points will be won't be non-coplanar, and the ones that are won't necessarily contain all the points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a point on a "vertical" line down the center of the frustum where the distance to an edge on the bottom and top of the frustum (assuming it's symmetrical) is the same.

solve such that a point on the bottom is Xb, Yb, Zb, a point on the top is Xt, Yt, Zt and the line is a point Xp, Yp, Zp plus a vector Ax, By, Cz.

so solve the equation

```
sqrt( (Xb - (Xp + VAx) )^2 + (Yb - (Yp + VBy))^2 + (Zb - (Zp + VCy))^2) = 
sqrt( (Xt - (Xp + VAx) )^2 + (Yt - (Yp + VBy))^2 + (Zt - (Zp + VCy))^2).
```

The only variable in there is the scalar V.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Solved it right after asking, as usual (must appease the forum gods). Projected it into 2D along the shortest axis, then simply stipulated that the radius of the sphere is the distance to both one of the "far" and "near" vertices. The maths kind of fell out from that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is correct but there's also the second possibility that Anthony's suggesting: you might be able to use a smaller sphere by moving the centre to the middle of the base, if the frustrum isn't too tall.

Comment: Yes, if the point is outside of the frustum you need to the intersection of the line and the bottom of the frustum. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking (according to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PyramidalFrustum.html)) the base of the frustum can be any polygon and, also strictly speaking, that polygon doesn't even have to be convex.  That said, to get a general solution to the problem, I think you might need to use (almost) all the vertices as suggested above.  There might be special cases, though, whose solution might (as suggested above) only require the comparison of a couple of spheres.   I like the link by Anthony above:  Megiddo provides a transformation that he claims yields a solution in O(n) (!) time. Not bad !