# Minimal enclosing sphere - derive from OBB?

Tags: collision-detection, bounding-box, bounding-volume

I need to compute the minimal enclosing sphere of a set of points in 3D, which is already enclosed by a oriented bounding box (OBB).

Is my assumption correct that the sphere can be derived from the OBB as follows?

```
sphere_radius = 0.5 * obb_diagonal
sphere_center = obb_center
```

If not,

- why?
- can the OBB used at all?

Comment: Can you please provide a definition for 'oriented bounding box'? (how is it oriented? does the orientation always guarantee a minimisation of the volume of the box?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the oriented bounding box may be arbitrarily oriented, then it's not guaranteed that you can construct a minimum bounding sphere directly from the oriented bounding box.

As a counterexample, consider a cubic bounding box from `(-1,-1,-1)` to `(1,1,1)`, containing the six points at the centre of the cube's faces: `(1,0,0)`, `(-1,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)`, `(0,-1,0)`, `(0,0,1)`, `(0,0,-1)`.

The minimal bounding sphere for this set of points would be a ball of radius 1, centred on `(0,0,0)`. The ball constructed by your suggested algorithm would be a ball of radius `1.7`(ish) centred on the origin.

Instead, you will want to use an algorithm to find the minimal bounding sphere. There exist algorithms to do this in linear time (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194812/finding-a-minimum-bounding-sphere-for-a-frustum) for pointers on where to look. 'Miniball' is a good search keyword.)